# Thread.sleep vs CountDownLatch.await with timeout

Tags: java, sleep, countdownlatch

I know that CountDownLatch is used to synchronize between processing in multiple threads. But my question is about using CountDownLatch for something it is not especially used for: waiting for some time before continuing executing instructions in the same thread.

```
//the countDown instance is not shared with any other thread
CountDownLatch countDown = new CountDownLatch(1);
try {
    //here I just want to "sleep" for one second
    countDown.await(1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
} catch (InterruptedException ex) {
    //handle exception
}
```

Obviously here, the await will only return after 1 second (nobody is countdowning the CountDownLatch).
I want to know if there is a difference between using this approach and simply using `Thread.sleep`, especially regarding CPU usage.

Even if the CountDownLatch instance is not shared between threads, the code snippet above is used in a context where multiple threads are running this code (so, each with its own CountDownLatch that is used only for the purpose of sleeping).

<s>A colleague of mine is stating that it is more (CPU) efficient to use countDownLatch.await(timeout), but I'm puzzled about the reasons.</s> If there are any reason (for any particular context) where such usage is more efficient than `Thread.sleep`, I want to know about it and about the reasons.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your colleague is wrong.  And regardless, it’s a sleeping operation, so who cares about efficiency?  The whole point is to do nothing for a specific period of time.

Comment: "but I'm puzzled about the reasons" did s/he explain the reasons? If so, what were they?

Comment: Not really, I don't have daily exchange with him. He does not really know the reasons. Anyway, It is not the most important part of the question.

Comment: If he/she/it/whatever doesn't know why, there is nothing to discuss. No reason to even ask anybody else, only the source of the disinformation.